# How to get the pid of nw.exe in node-webkit?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

How to to get PID of current instance of `nw.exe` in node-webkit from my JavaScript code?

Comment: what's result of `process.pid`?

Comment: Thank you, it returns pid of `nw.exe`.

Comment: @AndreySidorov can you please write that as an answer, so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

As nw exposes all node api in addition to DOM, you can use [process.pid](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_pid)